# 404 error in installing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to open this link: http://somedomain.com/somefolder/wp-admin/install.php for Wordpress installation but I get this:

> The requested URL /myftp/wordpress4.7.2/wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I'm definitely sure that the file exists in the directory and
By the way I'm pretty sure that I've entered the write values in the wp-config.php file for database, username and password. hostname is: localhost

Comment: Are you certain about that "somefolder" in your URL? What is the web root of your account? The wordpress4.7.2 folder is probably the issue, but its going to be tough for us to say without seeing your server setup

Comment: I was certain about the folder but I changed it anyway. now wp-admin folder resides directly in the root directory, and do you mean the domain name by web root?

Comment: The webroot would be set in your server's control panel.. Basically which folder on the file structure the domain name points to as it's root. If you have a basic hosting plan, you might only get one site per account and this wouldn't matter. You'd probably just want to be all the WP files directly in your root folder, unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise.

Comment: thank you . problem solved . I should have just move the files to public_html